# Show all records in one datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have 5 tables with `One to Many relationship` in MS Access and I want to show all the records that are saved in one `Datagridview`. The below code is for filling the `Datagridview` with the records in one table

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class DataGridView
Dim CON As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Employee.mdb;")
Private Sub DataGridView_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM employee"

    Dim ADAPTER As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, CON)
    Dim DT As New DataTable("employee")
    ADAPTER.Fill(DT)
    DataGridView2.DataSource = DT

    Dim SQL1 As String
    SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM employee"

    Dim ADAPTER1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL1, CON)
    Dim CMD1 As New OleDbCommand(SQL1, CON)
    CON.Open()

    Dim READER As OleDbDataReader = CMD1.ExecuteReader
    READER.Read()

    CON.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Is there anyway to show the records of the five tables in one `Datagridview`, replacing the code above?

Here's my tables and relationship:

[Employee's Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IATit.png)

Comment: a JOIN assumes the tables are related; its not clear how *that code* relates to the question or what it is playing at with a DataTable and a do-nothing Reader on the same db table.  Maybe add some details...  And also read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: To build on what Plutonix said: You need to provide more details about your tables. Your datagridview code should mostly work as is (though there's some unnecessary code), so it's just in your SQL query that changes would need to be made, and yet you've given people here zero information that could actually help them help you with the problems you're having

Comment: I have read the How to Ask and also read the Tour. Sorry for giving a zero information, I'll edit my question...

Comment: I tried to edit my answer and give some info... My professor gave the code above and said that it's one way of filling datagrid or showing records...

Comment: Sorry, we'd just be guessing at the table name, PKs etc.  This should help you with the concepts: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

Comment: Thank you for giving me a reference :) I'll read that and hopefully, it may answer my question :)